# Self-hosted log analyzer/viewer

Tags: logs

Does somebody know of a decent self-hosted log analyzer/viewer? Something like Google's [Log Analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/loganalyzer/) and [Log Analyzer 2](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/loggershark/).

Sought after features:

- Server based, self-hosted
- No specific tech preference, any language, any OS
- Define own log formats (we work with uncommon log formats)
- Open source preferred, but can also be commercial
- Filtering of log entries
- Collapsing of long log entries
- No need to store logs, only to view them in the user session

I would like to deploy it in our network so all people can upload and inspect the logs we work with. It would be nice if the app allows defining our own log formats that can be selected, just like Google's. I searched online, on GitHub and [Google Code](https://opensource.google/) but couldn't find anything similar.